# How to use erlang-cowboy to host an html document to a webpage on my server

Tags: networking, html

For example if the ip address of my server were 43.45.547.78 and I have erlang-cowboy installed on said server along with an html document "test.html". How using cowboy a program written in erlang, do I make it so that when I type the above ip address in to my browser I see what that html document displays in my browser. Also so that anyone who has access to the net can view said html doc by typing in the ip address of my server.